# Hot to put with httpclient? Rest(ish) API

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I'm working with the pipedrive API and trying to update a record (deal, but the endpoint isn't important).  The format of the is as follows.

```
https://companyDomain.pipedrive.com/api/v1/deals/DealID?api_token=API-Token
```

Where companydomain specifies your account with them, dealID is the ID we're updating and API token is the token supplied by pipedrive to access the API.  It's not a token that's returned by logging in, it's static one, **given on day one and never changes**.
HttpClient seems to want a base address so "https://companyDomain.pipedrive.com/", then something like the following:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(
        $"api/v1/deals/{dealId}/", args);
```

Where args is a class with the field/s and value/s I want to update.

If I include the api_token as fields in "args", it returns a 404 not found.  If I append it to the base url or the $api/v1/deals/{dealID}/ it returns permission denied.

Any suggestions as to how I can handle this?

I've managed to make a living coding for 30 years avoiding the web, now it's all anyone seems to want.  Appears I have to finally get a handle on this, hence the recent questions! ;-)

Thanks in advance

Jim

Comment: Have you tried making the URL `api/v1/deals/{dealId}?api_token={apiToken}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append it with a "?"
So your URL should look like api/v1/deals/YOUR_ID?api_token=THE_TOKEN

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(
    $"api/v1/deals/{dealId}?api_token={apiToken}", args);
```

Comment: Accepting this as it's basically right, but I also had to HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(args); to get it to work.  Thanks for the answers all, muchly appreciated :-)